# How do I fix the "Error: The Flutter directory is not a clone of the GitHub project." error when I'm trying to install flutter?

Tags: android, iphone, dart, flutter, flutter-test

I downloaded and installed git 2.18 easily and then I proceeded o download the zip SDK of flutter. Once I did that, I extracted it to my documents folder and then I updated the path in the "environmental variables" tab in the control panel:
[The Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxuif.png)

After this, I proceeded to make sure everything was working by typing in flutter into the control panel, and afterward, I got this error:
[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tERYS.png).
I tried fixing it by typing in the command that the error told me to enter, and afterward, I still got the error. Could someone please tell me how to fix this and also how to fix the mistake of typing in and entering the command from the error?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `git` is in your path by calling it. If it is not, add it to your path.

If this still won't work go to your flutter directory, delete it and rerun the `git clone` of the flutter repo.

Comment: How would I go about calling the checking/adding git to my path? I think that may be the problem actually as I only added flutter to my path.

Comment: Call `git -v`. If it doesn't respond add it to your path e.g. like described [here](http://www.chambaud.com/2013/07/08/adding-git-to-path-when-using-github-for-windows/)

Comment: I called git -v and although I'd get something if I typed git, it would say it doesn't recognize the -v part so I ended up following along that article you shared  with me. As I was going through the files, I found that there wasn't a git hub file in the local file, making it impossible for me to progress.  Do you know what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on mac sometimes you won't see hidden files in Finder app, which results in missing hidden files and folders like .git, .gitignore,.idea etc while copying to your flutter directory.  This causes similar error because of incomplete files

Press 'Shift' + 'cmd' + '.' buttons together to view hidden files and copy all files to flutter directory